# How to call async Task using the .Net framework v3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

How to call async Task Framework 3.5 please help me. I am calling this method in my 3.5 framework project its shows an error.any alternet way post json data using Framework 3.5 Here's my code:

```
public async void APIPushStatusDriverPostion(string direction,string carColor,string supplier_company,string SupplierAccountId,string Karho_Ref,string booking_id,string vehicale_type, string vehicle_id, string vehicle_plate, double latitude, double longitude, string carModel, string status, string driver_id, string driver_phone, string driver_first_name, string driver_last_name)
{
    APIKarhoBookingProperties objbooking = new APIKarhoBookingProperties();
    objbooking.vehicle.vehicle_type   = vehicale_type;
    objbooking.vehicle.vehicle_id     =    vehicle_id;
    objbooking.vehicle.vehicle_plate  = vehicle_plate;
    objbooking.vehicle.latitude       =   latitude;
    objbooking.vehicle.longitude      =    longitude;
    objbooking.vehicle.eta_minutes    = "null";
    objbooking.vehicle.make           = "null";
    objbooking.vehicle.model = carModel;
    objbooking.vehicle.color = carColor;
    objbooking.vehicle.status = status;
    objbooking.vehicle.driver_id = driver_id;
    objbooking.vehicle.driver_phone = driver_phone;
    objbooking.vehicle.driver_phone = driver_first_name;
    objbooking.vehicle.driver_last_name = driver_last_name;          

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objbooking);
    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("{supplier_id}/availability?version=2", json))
    {
        string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

}
```

Comment: .net 3.5 don't have async Task. I know if want use it. we can upgrade .net 4.5

Comment: You should tell us what the error is.

Comment: You cannot do this with framework 3.5.

Comment: There is a Nuget package to add async to older version of .NET - see https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35

Comment: any alternate way ? how call to post data json format

Comment: i can't change my framework ;(

Comment: Check rbm link, you don't have to change your target framework, it is just a package adding the functionalities you want to the .NET 3.5 framework

Comment: @rbm Even if he uses the AsyncBridge the HttpClient class is only available in the 4.5 version of the .Net framework.

Comment: Fair point, you're right, he'd need to switch to `WebClient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the 3.5 version of the .Net framework. Your solutions are:

1. Not use the async/await/Task based methods or
2. Change the target framework to something more recent like the 4.6 version or
3. Use [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.WebClient(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) if your use-case is simple and if it's not (ex: manipulating headers, etc) then use the [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) object:

Here's an example using the [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.WebClient(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It might not work correctly depending on how you're setting up your [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string responseData = client.UploadString(host + "{supplier_id}/availability?version=2", json);
}
```

Comment: It's the domain name (`http://example.com`) since `"{supplier_id}/availability?version=2"` is not a valid URL and the host was not included in your original answer. If you include the code you used to create the `httpClient` I might help you with that.

Comment: There is no async part in this answer.

Comment: @ZbigniewLedwoń of course not. You missed this part "This is not possible using the 3.5 version of the .Net framework"

Comment: No, I did not missed it @Nasreddine. What about  System.Threading in .NET Framework 3.5?